# Bootstrap4 JQuery Responsive Tabs Working Incorrectly, Snippet provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've inserted a snippet to show the problem. In my actual code I am using a jinga forloop to create the cards.

Each card has responsive tabs.

However when you click on card 2's tabs to see card 2's data, it displays the 1st card's data in the tabs of the 1st card.

However, the data such as name and age is shown correctly for card 2 as there is no tab clicking to display that.

Essentially each card's tabs should show THAT card's data.

This problem is solved when I make the `href="#profile"` in the `nav-link` class and `id="profile"` different for the two cards.

Such as `href="#profile"` and `id="profile"` for card 1 and

`href="#Profile"` and `id="Profile"` for card 2.

However because I'm running a for loop to instantiate the cards, I can't do this.

Can anyone help me?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

html,
body {
  background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.card h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, red);
  width: 18rem;
}

.card a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="padding-success">
          <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">


            <!-- Card Navbar -->
            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#company" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <!-- Card Navbar content -->
              <div class="card-body tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">

                  <div class="card-body padding-success">
                    <h3 class="marker">Jane Jones</h3>
                    <h3 class="marker">43</h3>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- about tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="bio">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Jane Jones: Hi there</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- videos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="company">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Jane Jones: my dog</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of navbar tabs -->
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Card Navbar 2 -->
            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#company" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- Card Navbar content -->
              <div class="card-body tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
                  <div class="card-body padding-success">
                    <h3 class="marker">Bob Jones</h3>
                    <h3 class="marker">43</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- about tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="bio">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Bob Jones card: Hi</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- videos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="company">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Bob Jones card: cheese</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of navbar tabs -->
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap min.CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 min.js-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <!-- Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 min.js-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You cant assign the same id to multiple elements since IDs are unique to each element. You need to give a unique id to each of them as you initially tried above or use a common class name and target the class instead.

Comment: Forgive me I'm a beginner but how would I do that if the cards are being created from a forloop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same id in two elements which a really bad idea...the id should be unique for each element

Since you are running a loop i can suggest using data attributes instead

For each loop you can assign a custom attribute to your element (`data-profile=1`) and for herf you can use `href= "[data-profile='1']"` and then increment the number accordingly

see snippet code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

html,
body {
  background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.card h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, red);
  width: 18rem;
}

.card a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="padding-success">
          <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">


            <!-- Card Navbar -->
            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="[data-profile='1']" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="[data-bio='1']" data-toggle="tab">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="[data-company='1']" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <!-- Card Navbar content -->
              <div class="card-body tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" data-profile='1'>

                  <div class="card-body padding-success">
                    <h3 class="marker">Jane Jones</h3>
                    <h3 class="marker">43</h3>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- about tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" data-bio='1'>
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Jane Jones: Hi there</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- videos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" data-company='1'>
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Jane Jones: my dog</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of navbar tabs -->
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Card Navbar 2 -->
            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="[data-profile='2']" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="[data-bio='2']" data-toggle="tab">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="[data-company='2']" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- Card Navbar content -->
              <div class="card-body tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" data-profile='2'>
                  <div class="card-body padding-success">
                    <h3 class="marker">Bob Jones</h3>
                    <h3 class="marker">43</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- about tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" data-bio='2'>
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Bob Jones card: Hi</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- videos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane"data-company='2'>
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Bob Jones card: cheese</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of navbar tabs -->
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap min.CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 min.js-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <!-- Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 min.js-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, another beginner question, how would I set the data attribute to increment with each loop?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Django so I'll need to look into how to do that with the `{{ forloop.counter }}` I think, thank you anyways.

Comment: You may want to reword and add more info/code to your question so that the community can assist you better

Comment: @Chiller I've gotten it working by putting `{{forloop.counter}}` in place of the `1` so thank you very much for your help. I will mark this as the best answer.

Comment: @brooksrelyt Thank you, I'm still new at coding, I'm trying to get better at asking questions, I added a snippet for the first time in this post hehe, but I will try in my next question!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Id to each of the instances.

```
#bio
```

and

```
#bio2
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

html,
body {
  background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.card h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, red);
  width: 18rem;
}

.card a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="padding-success">
          <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">


            <!-- Card Navbar -->
            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#company" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <!-- Card Navbar content -->
              <div class="card-body tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">

                  <div class="card-body padding-success">
                    <h3 class="marker">Jane Jones</h3>
                    <h3 class="marker">43</h3>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- about tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="bio">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Jane Jones: Hi there</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- videos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="company">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Jane Jones: my dog</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of navbar tabs -->
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Card Navbar 2 -->
            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile2" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#bio2" data-toggle="tab">Bio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#company2" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- Card Navbar content -->
              <div class="card-body tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile2">
                  <div class="card-body padding-success">
                    <h3 class="marker">Bob Jones</h3>
                    <h3 class="marker">43</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- about tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="bio2">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Bob Jones card: Hi</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- videos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="company2">
                  <div class="padding-all">
                    <p class="card-text">Bob Jones card: cheese</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of navbar tabs -->
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap min.CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 min.js-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <!-- Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 min.js-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: How can I do that if the cards are being created from a forloop? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: I don't see a forloop. What do  you mean?

Comment: I mentioned in the explanation, this snippet is just for demonstration purposes, in my actual code I am creating instances of the card by using a forloop, ex) for user in  users, a card is created for each instance of a user